# Why is `rake assets:precompile` throwing "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"? (re: asset_sync)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline, cdn, fog

I am trying to set up my rails app to upload its assets to Amazon's AWS S3 using the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem, following [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31). I know I've got my S3 stuff configured right because my app is otherwise able to upload images to S3. I'm pretty sure I've got all the settings correct:

```
FOG_DIRECTORY => mybucketname
FOG_PROVIDER  => AWS
FOG_REGION    => s3-us-west-2
```

Yet I keep getting an error:

```
-bash> heroku run rake assets:precompile --remote staging
Running rake assets:precompile attached to terminal... up, run.1
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
mkdir -p /app/public/assets
...
mkdir -p /app/public/assets
AssetSync: Syncing.
rake aborted!
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known                                # <-- error
```

Compiling locally produces a slightly different error:

```
-bash> bundle exec rake assets:precompile
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
mkdir -p /Users/bart/Dev/MyApp/myapp/public/assets
...
mkdir -p /Users/bart/Dev/MyApp/myapp/public/assets
AssetSync: Syncing.
rake aborted!
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known             # <-- error
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I traced the error down to [a 'connection' line in Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/33c1aec7e026a4c3bf97054d3335cd3c3eda4339/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb#L291), one of `asset_sync`'s runtime dependencies, and it turns out that **my `FOG_REGION` was set incorrectly**. In my case, the region should have been `us-west-2`, not `s3-us-west-2`.

It has been a while since I configured my S3 account, so I first tried to determine what region I was using by logging into the AWS S3 console, clicking on the bucket name, and then clicking "Properties". There, the region is listed as *Oregon*. Well, that didn't work. So then I clicked through the objects and folders browser of one of my existing buckets until I got to an asset, looked up its "Properties", and saw the "Link":

https://*s3-us-west-2*.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/uploads/mymodel/image/1135/myimage.jpg

I was convinced that `s3-us-west-2` was correct until I noticed that [Fog adds the s3- prefix](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/33c1aec7e026a4c3bf97054d3335cd3c3eda4339/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb#L284).

Anyway, I now know that once you find out your region by name (e.g. Oregon), you can look it up in [this list of S3 regions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) (it's the name under the column *Location Constraint*).

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Great answer. Still can't understand why Amazon such a large company have a very poor UI